# Python unexpected EOF while parsing : syntax error

Tags: python

I am trying to do a simple toto history with a dictionary and function however I have this funny syntax error that keeps appearing that states "unexpected EOF while parsing" on the python shell when I try to runs it. I re-looked over and over however I cannot find the error. I used input for input of integers therefore I do not think that the problem might lie with the input or raw_input. Please help me ! Below are my codes and the error on the python shell.

```
options()
choice = input ("Enter your choice: ")
print

while choice != -1:
    if choice == 1:
        print("Choice 1")
        for key in toto_book:
            print key + "\t" + "Day: " + toto_book[key][0] + '\t' + 'Winning         Numbers: ' + str(toto_book[key][1] + 'Additional Number: ' + toto_book[key][2]
    elif choice == 2:
        print("Choice 2")
        draw = raw_input("Enter draw date(dd/mm/yy): ")
        if draw in toto_book:
            print (draw + "\t" + "Day: " + toto_book[draw][0] + "\t" + "Winning Numbers: " + str(toto_book[draw][1]) + 'Additional Number: ' + toto_book[draw][2])            
        else:
            print draw + ' cannot be found.'
```

There is a syntax error at the `elif choice == 2:` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

As pointed out by @cricket_007, this answer is based on the false assumption that Python 3 is being used. Actually, Python 2 is being used and the only serious problem is that the call to `str` is missing a closing parenthesis.

---

You are using Python 3 in which `print` is a function, not a statement (as it is in Python 2).

This is the line causing the problem:

```
    print key + "\t" + "Day: " + toto_book[key][0] + '\t' + 'Winning         Numbers: ' + str(toto_book[key][1] + 'Additional Number: ' + toto_book[key][2]
```

Add parentheses to make `print` a function call, i.e. `print(...)`:

```
print(key + "\t" + "Day: " + toto_book[key][0] + '\t' + 'Winning         Numbers: ' + str(toto_book[key][1]) + 'Additional Number: ' + toto_book[key][2])
```

Also, the call to `str()` was missing the closing parenthesis.

There is a similar problem on line 15.

---

Other problems:

- `input()` returns a string, not an integer so your `if choice ==`
  statements will never be true. Either convert `choice` to an integer
  with `choice = int(choice)` after the `input()`, or use a string in
  the `if` statements, e.g. `if choice == '1'`.
- The `while` loop is infinte, and unnecessary for the code shown (perhaps it is a work in progress?).

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much however I now have a problem. As I used the dictionary toto_book, my code goes:

``if choice == 1:
    print("Choice 1")
    for key in toto_book:
        print (key + "\t" + "Day: " + toto_book[key][0] + '\t' + 'Winning Numbers: ' + str(toto_book[key][1]) + '\t' + 'Additional Number: ' + toto_book[key][2])``

However the results I gotten from the python shell are not what I inputted in order. As in the keys are jumbled up. Can you help ?

Comment: What indication is there that this is Python3 and not 2? `raw_input` is a Python 2 function

Comment: And yes its a work in progress . The while loop is finite as I have a end program if choice == -1 at the end. I did not post it.

Comment: @cricket_007: thank's for pointing that out - you're right. I only noticed the first `input()` and assumed Python 3 from that. Actually I was wrong, and therefore also wrong about `choice` being converted to an integer, and again `print` being a function. So the problem was only that `str()` was missing a paren, so at least I got something right :) Hard to believe that the OP accepted this answer - I'd delete it otherwise.

Comment: @Boeing: re dict keys, perhaps you iterate over the sorted keys, if that is the same as the order of input? Otherwise you could use an [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which will keep the keys in order of creation.

Comment: @Boeing777: I've updated the answer to correct my invalid assumptions.

Comment: @mhawke: Hi I am really sorry but I am currently a student learning programming and is rather new.. May I know how should I use the `collections.OrderedDict()` ?

Comment: @Boeing777: it's pretty much the same as an ordinary dict. There's documentation with examples [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects). So, however you are creating `toto_book` now, just use the `OrderedDict` instead.